# Access Array via Index

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I tried figuring this out by reading both how the Tags are handled in the Todo-List Example and how the RSVPS are handled in the Parties example, but I could not figure out a general way to achieve my Goal.
I have a Plan Collection which has a name ownerid and excerciselist

> Plans.insert({name: names[i], ownerId: 1, excerciselist: excercises});

Now in this Excerciselist, I want to add an undefined Amout of Excercises by ID.
I have an Excercisecollection with the following:

> Excercises.insert({name: names[i], muscle: muscles[i], device: devices[i], description: descriptions[i]});

Now all these Excercises have a unique _id element by default.
Adding things to the excerciselist no Problem I can do that by Push.
But what I can not figure out is, how I can access only certain ID's in the excerciselist via it's Index.

I can only access the whole Stringarray and output in in HTML via

> {{#each planarray}}
>           {{excerciselist}}
>           
>       {{/each}}
>   But there is no possiblity to do smoething like
>   {{ excerciselist }}

I have also tried returning only excerciselist to the planarray, but the problem is that because it is only indexed and not mapped it can not be accessed by the LiveHTML.

Does anyone have an Idea how this problem could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a field for the unique id to the Excersies insert?

```
Excercises.insert({ uniqueID: [i], name: names[i], muscle: muscles[i], device: devices[i], description: descriptions[i]});
```

This way you can get just the excercise you want based on the uniqueID-field.

Oh and you should probably call "uniqueID" something that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little Workaround which is not exactly what I had in mind but it gets the job done.

```
  Template.editplan.excercises = function() {
    var names = [];
    var add = [];
    var adder = null;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.excerciselist.length; i++)
    {
      add[i] = [];
      adder = Excercises.find({_id: this.excerciselist[i]});
      add[i]['_id'] = this.excerciselist[i];
      add[i]['location'] = i;
      adder.forEach(function (obj) {
        add[i]['name'] = obj.name;
      });
      names.push(add[i]);
    }
    return names;
  };
```

Basically I made a new Array in which i put the Data I want to have so I can read it in the LiveHTML see example below

```
{{#each planarray}}
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
        {{#each excercises}}
        {{name}}
        {{/each}}
        <select name="selectedexcercise{{_id}}" id="selectedexcercise{{_id}}">
            {{> excerciseoption}}
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="addtoplan" value="Eine Übung hinzfügen">
    {{/each}}
```

But there must be a more efficient or nice way.... At least I hope so!